# ¿Cómo puedo en java pasar al disco un pdf que generé con jaspersoft? Esto con el fin de poder enviarlo como adjunto por correo - Spring boot

Tags: java, pdf, email, jasper

Este es el código con el que genero el reporte pdf usando spring boot. Funciona correctamente. El asunto es que el pdf se genera en memoria para poder descargarse cuando se invoque una API. Pero tambien necesito poder enviar el pdf por correo. Los ejemplo que encuentro de envio de archivos por correo, el archivo lo obtiene de una ubicación en disco.

```
   try
    {
        //Compiled report
        InputStream jasperStream = (InputStream) this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/reports/Inscripcion.jasper");


        //Adding attribute names
        Map params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("pCiudad", "medellin");
        params.put("pImpres", "fulano de tal");
        
        // Fetching the inscripcion from the data database.
        final JRBeanCollectionDataSource source = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource(lstInscripciones); 

        JasperReport jasperReport = (JasperReport) JRLoader.loadObject(jasperStream);
        JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, source);

        response.setContentType("application/x-pdf");
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=Inscripcion.pdf");

        final ServletOutputStream outStream = response.getOutputStream();
        JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(jasperPrint, outStream);
    }
    catch (JRException excepJRE) 
    {
        log.error(excepJRE.getMessage());
    }   
    catch (IOException excepIO)
    {
        log.error(excepIO.getMessage());
    }
```

//Codigo para enviar correo:  Funciona Ok

```
        MimeMessage msg = javaMailSender.createMimeMessage();
    try {
        MimeMessageHelper helper = new MimeMessageHelper(msg, true);
        helper.setTo(request.getTo());
        helper.setFrom(Remitente);

        String html = "<div><h1><span>Hello Enviando desde Java</span></h1><blockquote><p><span>"+ request.getText() +".</span></p></blockquote><p>&nbsp;</p><p><span></span></p></div>";         

        helper.setText(html, true); 
        helper.setSubject(request.getSubject());
                
            //en caso de llevar adjunto se agregan las siguientes dos lineas:
            File file = new File("src/main/resources/archivos_pdf/inscripcion.pdf");
            helper.addAttachment(file.getName(), file);                
                
        javaMailSender.send(msg);
    }catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        return "correo fallido; " + e.getMessage();
    }
```

Ambos codigos funcionan bien haciendo lo que deben. Me gustaría saber cómo puedo pasar el archivo pdf (que genero en memoria) al disco local para después poder enviarlo por correo.

Answer (score 0):

Encontré la solución. Primero, debo pasar a byte el archivo pdf que se creó en memoria:

```
byte[] archivoEnBytes = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
```

Después debo convertir los bytes en un archivo y darle una ubicación en disco.:

```
FileOutputStream fileOuputStream = new FileOutputStream("D:\\FolderPrueba\\nits_2.pdf");
fileOuputStream.write(adjuntoByte);
fileOuputStream.close();
```

Y por último, adjunto el nuevo archivo creado para ser enviado por correo:

```
  File file = new File("D:\\FolderPrueba\\nits_2.pdfnits_2.pdf"); helper.addAttachment("nits_2.pdf",file);
```